# Finding integral for this question-

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals

$$F(x)=
\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{(\sqrt{sin(x)}+\sqrt{cos(x)} )^4}dx = $$

Any help would be highly appreciated.I first used an online integral finder  but it only displayed me final answer which was =.33333 .

PS: I am still in high school so complex answers wouldn't be of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide the numerator and denominator by $\cos^2{x}$:
$$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec^2{x}}{{\left(\sqrt{\tan{x}}+1\right)}^4} \; dx$$
Let $u=\tan{x}$:
$$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{du}{{\left(\sqrt{u}+1\right)}^4}$$
Let $w=\sqrt{u}+1$:
$$I=-\frac{1}{w^2}+\frac{2}{3w^3} \bigg \rvert_1^{\infty}=\boxed{\frac{1}{3}}$$